# Use of undeclared identifier 'completionCallback'

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am attempting to identify when a sound has finished playing by using the `AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion` method.  The 4th parameter expects a C function, which I have implemented below.  I recieve the error message,

`Use of undeclared identifier 'completionCallback' (first use in this function)` when referencing it.  None of the online examples I've seen has ever used `[self completionCallback]`, and they have no issues.

Where am I going wrong?

```
-(void)playAndRelease{
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion (_soundID,NULL,NULL,completionCallback,(void*) self);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_soundID);
}

void completionCallback (SystemSoundID  mySSID, void* myself) {
    //NSLog(@"completion Callback");
    AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion (mySSID);
    [(SoundEffect*)myself release];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, yes. Sometimes, an error messaqge means exactly what it says. `completionCallback` needs to be defined above `playAndRelease`.

First option: declare, but don't implement, `completionCallback`.

```
void completionCallback (SystemSoundID  mySSID, void* myself);

-(void)playAndRelease{
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion (_soundID,NULL,NULL,completionCallback,(void*) self);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_soundID);
}

void completionCallback (SystemSoundID  mySSID, void* myself) {
    //NSLog(@"completion Callback");
    AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion (mySSID);
    [(SoundEffect*)myself release];
}
```

Or define it fully ahead of time:

```
static void completionCallback (SystemSoundID  mySSID, void* myself) {
    //NSLog(@"completion Callback");
    AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion (mySSID);
    [(SoundEffect*)myself release];
}

-(void)playAndRelease{
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion (_soundID,NULL,NULL,completionCallback,(void*) self);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_soundID);
}
```

See also:

- [Wikipedia: Function prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype)

Comment: Thank you.  Starting obj-c. Pure ignorance. :)

Comment: Glad to help. This is a C principle, are you new to C as well? If so, I'll try to dig up a link to help.

Comment: Nevermind that last comment: I added a link to the Wikipedia article on this.